# Error [Help 1] Sakai 2.9.x installation

Tags: maven, tomcat, installation, sakai

I follow this instructions at [**Sakai Development Environment Setup Walkthrough**](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Development+Environment+Setup+Walkthrough).

I used 2.9.x Sakai version.

At step 11-C :

> Execute mvn -Pcafe clean install to build the minimal version (cafe)
>   of Sakai using maven.

I have an error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project kernel-deploy: Could not resolve depen
dencies for project org.sakaiproject:kernel-deploy:pom:2.9-SNAPSHOT: Could not f
ind artifact org.sakaiproject.entitybroker:entitybroker-assembly:zip:tomcat-over
lay:1.5.4-SNAPSHOT in sakai-maven2-snapshots (http://source.sakaiproject.org/mav
en2-snapshots) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
lutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :kernel-deploy
```

And I tried  `mvn clean install` it gave me error.

Please Help to solve it .
[image]

Comment: A look at [sakai-maven-snapshots](http://source.sakaiproject.org/maven2-snapshots) repo reveals the concerned artifact does not exist. You should probably try the newer version

Comment: @Raghuram newer version 10 ???

Comment: Yeah, 2.9 is old. For 2.9 you either need to use the sakai-2.9.x-all branch or you should use something newer like 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'cafe' build profile of Sakai is no longer maintained. Just do a full build. When you have built everything then you can build individual modules that you modify and it will be quick.

The startup time of Sakai is now under 30 seconds so the cafe build doesn't really give much anymore (it used to when processors were slower, the build took an hour and the startup would take several minutes :)

Comment: What i need to do then i didn't get it. i cant do full build cause i get this error .

Comment: Run the command as 'mvn clean install -X' and see what the error is. Are you behind a proxy?